# Differential dependence of the solutions on the initial conditions and on the parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the differential equations

$$ \frac{\partial\varphi_{j}}{\partial t}(t,x,\epsilon) = F^{j}(t,\varphi_{j}(t,x,\epsilon),\epsilon), \quad\text{for}\quad j=0,1,\cdots, M $$

with the initial values,

\begin{align}
\varphi_{0}(0,x,\epsilon)&=x,\\
\varphi_{j}(\alpha_{j}(x,\epsilon),x,\epsilon)&=\varphi_{j-1}(\alpha_{j}(x,\epsilon),x,\epsilon), \quad\text{for}\quad j=1,2,\cdots,M.
\end{align}

Here $F^{j}:S^{1}\times \mathbb{R}^{d}\times (\epsilon_{0},\epsilon_{0})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d} $, for $j=0,1,\cdots, M$ are $C^{r}$ functions and $\alpha_{j}$ represents a time variable.

I want to show inductively that $\alpha_{j}(x,\epsilon)$ and $\varphi_{j}$ are $C^{r}$ functions, for $j=0,1,\cdots, M$. I know that using the differential dependence of ODEs on the initial conditions (Theorem), we can show that $\varphi_{j}$ are $C^{r}$ functions for $j=0,1,\cdots, M$, however I don't know if we can use this Theorem in order to show the same assertion for $\alpha_{j}$. So I would be grateful if someone can help me clarify this question.